# Insert dot symbol with C# to mySQL error

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm facing a strange problem, I do an INSERT query to MySQL DB

```
                string site = txtSite.Text;
                string query = "INSERT INTO `site`(`id`, `url`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,?url, 1)";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?url", site);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?url", "abc.com");
                cmd.Connection = (MySqlConnection)connection;
                cmd.Prepare();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

1. If I enter "abc.com" into textbox txtSite, and run the code, it said error

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

2. But if I don't get value of txtSite, I put "abc.com" to ?url directly, the cmd run OK, not error.

Can you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a syntax issue. The following code may work for you.

```
string site = txtSite.Text;
string query = "INSERT INTO `site`(`id`, `url`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, @url, 1)";

MySqlClientconn conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.Open();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Prepare();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", site);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am assuming you are using the MySQL Connector/Net library. Don't forget to close the connection and dispose of the command and the connection when you are done.

**Reference**

For more info on using the MySQL Connector/Net library, see the following:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

Comment: Thank Steve, my issue is at connection, I created it like Singleton, it didn't work. I did create connection every run query, and it worked.